# How can I join the last X entries in a string array?

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

I've got an array like this:

```
string[] parts = line.Split(',');

string store = parts[0];
string sku = parts[1];
string subcatcode = parts[2];
string price = parts[3];
string date = parts[4];
string desc = parts[5];
```

I want description to equal the joined value of all the parts with an index of 5 or higher. Will this work or is there a better way to do it?

```
string desc = string.Join(",", parts.Skip(5).ToArray());
```

The issue is that the last part of the CSV I'm parsing can contain commas (parts 0-4 are guaranteed not to).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just specify a maximum count when you call [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx)?

```
string[] parts = line.Split(','.ToCharArray(), 6);
```

The last element (which you will assign to description) will include everything else, including the commas.

For data like `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"` this will give you `{ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6,7,8" }`

Comment: will this choke if a line has less than the specified count?

Comment: Count is the maximum it will return, so no, it shouldn't choke.  (Of course, if you say parts[5] you might get an exception thrown if there weren't enough parts)

Answer (score 0):

Sure this should work just fine. If you want to get rid of the trailing comma's you can .TrimEnd() your string first.